# Laravel 4.x, auth system failed on IIS

Tags: php, authentication, iis, laravel

I'm using auth system like here: http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

Simple as its described, nothing special - on my localhost works very well, but on IIS I couldn't logged in. This is always drop me back to the form page.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the log say anything? Did you check your DB?

Comment: Yes, I've checked.. nothing wrong.

Comment: Are any cookies set? If you add extra logging to your controller can you see if the login was successful?

Comment: This is due to PHP being installed as a CGI script.  I have seen how to fix it in linux as so:  http://codetheory.in/fixing-laravel-basic-auth-failure/   . It must be something similar with  IIS.